# Multiple content_for for specifying classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following little problem.

In layout I yield to **content_for** to set up some classes on my body tag:

```
<body class="<%= yield(:body_classes) %>
```

They I would like to call **content_for**

```
<%= content_for(:body_classes, "one") %>
```

So far so good. I use **content_for** for the second time:

```
<%= content_for(:body_classes, "two") %>
```

In my HTML I get the following:

```
<body class="onetwo">
```

Is there an elegant way to separate those two classes by space?  I can think of couple of hacky solution, but nothing feels right...

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `content_for` is a good fit in this case. However, you can solve the problem elegantly with a couple of helper methods (extracted from one of my Rails projects):

```
def klass(*classes)
  @classes = [] if @classes.nil?
  @classes += classes
  @classes.uniq!
  nil
end

def has_klass?(klass)
  !@classes.nil? && @classes.include?(klass)
end

def body_klasses
  @classes.map(&:to_s).join(" ") rescue nil
end
```

Usage in templates:

```
<%= klass :one, :two %>
<%= klass :three %>
```

In the layout, determine if a certain class is set:

```
<% if has_klass? :one %>
```

And finally...

```
<body class="<%= body_klasses %>">
```

You can further customize these to better suit your needs.

Comment: Seems like the cleanest way I've seen so far.

Comment: You can clean this up even further by replacing the last line with `<body<%= body_klasses ? " class='#{body_klasses}'".html_safe : nil %>>` ... That will remove `class=` when no klass is set

Answer (score 0):

Just put a space before (or after) the class each time you set `content_for`.

```
<% content_for(:body_classes, "one ") %>
```

By the way, you probably don't want the `=` in your setting tags; you generally don't want Rails to output into the HTML the content you're storing away for later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check, before adding something to :body_clases, if there´s something already in it, in order to add the space before adding the new content.

```
<% content_for(:body_classes,content_for?(:body_classes) ? ' one' : 'one') %>
<% content_for(:body_classes,content_for?(:body_classes) ? ' two' : 'two') %>
```

The final Html will be:

```
<body class="one two">
```